# How do I decide if it's ok to pool data?

Tags: r, biostatistics, pooling, diversity

I have biodiversity data (fish species, and their individual length, through electrofishing) from 8 different stretches of the same river, for 7 different seasons.
We would like to see if it's ok to pool the data from those 8 stretches, for each season.
I have calculated a biodiversity index for each stretch and season, which accounts for the number of captures.

Something like this:

```r
read.csv(text = "stretch,season,bio_index\n1,autumn 2019,3.8\n2, 
  autumn 2019,4\n3, autumn 2019,2.8")
 #>   stretch       season bio_index
 #> 1       1  autumn 2019       3.8
 #> 2       2  autumn 2019       4.0
 #> 3       3  autumn 2019       2.8
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

How do I decide if the values of that index between the 8 stretches, within a season, are close enough for pooling the capture data?

Comment: For what purpose do you want to pool the data? If there is a practical difference between biodiversity 2.8 and 4.0, I would would not pool the data in a report of results. If no practical difference maybe give averages with a footnote saying all observed values were within (something like) $\pm 1.0,$ if true. // If you're asking about comparing 2 seasons with a t test, then use a Welch t test which allows from different season-to-season variances. // I some other purpose, then please explain in more detail why you're asking.

Comment: Thank you, Bruce. You are right, of course it depends on the purpose. First we want to basically extrapolate total numbers of fish in the stream, but also look for trends within species, changes in species composition, all across years/seasons. I guess the best is to report differences in stretches when possible.